# Why does com.mysql.jdbc.Driver take forever to open in MATLAB?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I'm having an issue with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in MATLAB and I'm hoping someone else has run into it and can help me out.  Basically, my problem is that on one machine, every time I call `database('mysql.jdbc.Driver', ...)`, that call takes approximately 30 seconds.  I would just chalk this up as normal except that when I run the same script on a different machine, it the call to `database` takes about 15 seconds the first time, and less than 1 second every time after.  Once I have the database connection, running queries takes the same amount of time no matter what machine I'm working on.

Has anyone else run into (and solved) this issue?  My best guess is that there's some sort of environment issue causing the problem, but I have no idea even where to begin looking.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to mysql from each machine through other means like the mysql client executable?  You'll want to figure out if it's a network or authentication delay or if this is particular to the jdbc driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was some sort of networking / service issue.  When I turned off some of the unneeded services (Wireless Zero Configuration among others), I went from a consistent 20 seconds to create the connection to a few milliseconds.  I wish I had paid better attention to the services I changed, but hopefully this helps someone else.

Thanks to Mr. Fooz for suggesting using something else, that allowed me to confirm that it was a system issue, and not MATLAB specific.